# Preprocessing file with unix commands in fread on a Windows machine

Tags: r, awk, grep, data.table

To avoid loading a large dataset (> 7 million rows) into R I would like to pre-process it. The intention was to use either `grep` or `gawk` in `fread()` from `data.table` package.

Here is a hugely simplified example of the dataset (`test.dat`);

```
0.678 324 765
8.001 109 425
4.425 765 124
3.463 425 765
```

I would like to match on ID columns 2 and 3 and return column 1. Have tried using `grep` with no success really;

```
library(data.table)
# id <- 425
fread("grep 425 test.dat", header = FALSE)
#       V1  V2  V3
# 1: 8.001 109 425
# 2: 4.425 765 124 # <-- incorrect match
# 3: 3.463 425 765
```

And no, `-w` does not help me as suggested on different places on the web as the decimal is considered as punctuation marking end of a word.

Then I tried `awk` or in fact `gawk` as I am on a Windows 10 machine;

```
fread("gawk '$2==425 {print $1}' test.dat", header = FALSE)
#       V1
# 1: 3.463
```

Worked for matching on second column, so I extended to match on either column 2 and 3;

```
fread("gawk '$2==425||$3==425 {print $1}' test.dat", header = FALSE)
# Error in fread("gawk '$2==425||$3==425 {print $1}' test.dat"  : 
#   File is empty: ...
```

Other attempts;

```
fread("gawk '$2==\"425\"||$3==\"425\" {print $1}' test.dat", header = FALSE)
# Error in fread("gawk '$2==\"425\"||$3==\"425\" {print $1}' test.dat",  : 
#    File is empty: ...

fread("gawk '{ if ($2==425 || $3==425) print $1; }' test.dat")
# print was unexpected at this time.
# Error in fread("gawk '{ if ($2==425 || $3==425) print $1; }' test.dat",  : 
#    File not found: ...
# In addition: Warning messages:
# 1: running command ... had status 1 
# 2: In shell(paste("(", input, ") > ", tt, sep = "")) :
#   '(gawk '{ if ($2==425 || $3==425) print $1; }' test.dat) > ..' execution failed with error code 1
```

I tested the attempts on a linux machine which did give me the desired result. I have been searching and trying different solutions, but to no avail. Anyone got a suggestion?

Here is my `sessionInfo()` if needed;

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.10.4    RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0   RevoUtils_10.0.4 tools_3.4.0
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `sprintf` from fread's `input` argument? fread's documentation shows you can enter `grep` commands directly into fread and it'll run. E.g., `fread("grep blah filename")`

Comment: @everetr, thats not the probelm - as you can see the first grep I tried worked as it was meant to, but not what i desired. I will edit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it is supported on windows, but here goes a solution that works on linux with grep:

```
fread("grep ' 425 \\| 425$' test.dat", header = F)
```

Here is how it work:

1. the first pattern matches `' 425 '`, which checks for the number of interest enclosed by space (so, it won't match `4.425` or `14251`)
2. the second pattern matches `' 425[end of line]'`, because the first pattern would not catch that
3. the two patterns are concatenated using the `|` operator, which is doubly escaped `\` (the `\` character needing to be escaped itself)

In case the csv file is comma separated, this should work:

```
fread("grep ',425,\\|,425$' test.dat", header = F)
```

Comment: you sparked a thought with the double escaping - I decided to replace the single quotes with escaped double quotes (i.e. `\"`). That worked! Also solved the errors for my previous attempts. :) Thanks! So, your solution indeed worked on linux but on windows this worked; `fread("grep \",425,\\|,425$\" test.dat", header = F)`

Answer (score 0):

supported on windows:

```
fread('grep -v "^[04]." test.dat', header = T)
#      V1  V2  V3
#1: 8.001 109 425
#2: 3.463 425 765
fread('grep  "[^.]425" test.dat', header = F)
#      V1  V2  V3
#1: 8.001 109 425
#2: 3.463 425 765
```